# How to optimize OpenMp code,For example Histogram

Tags: c++, optimization, parallel-processing, openmp

I am dealing with huge point cloud data. I try to use OpenMp.
But I found it's very hard for beginners to optimize code.
For example, when I want to get the Histogram of the point cloud (the point has another info beyond x,y,z). I write code below

```
 #pragma omp parallel num_threads(N_THREAD) shared(hist,partHist)
    {
        int tId = omp_get_thread_num();
        int index = tId * partCount; 
        #pragma omp for nowait
        for(int i =0;i<partCount;++i)
        {
            if (index + i < size)
                #pragma omp atomic
                partHist[tId][(int)floor((array[index + i] - minValue) / stride)]++;
        }
        #pragma omp critical
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < binCount; ++i)
                hist[i] += partHist[tId][i];
        }
    }
```

The code is being run on Linux with an i7-9700k, compiled with g++ and using omp 4.0

I have two questions

1. The data set is about 10^8 at least, I use 128 threads. but It's slower than serial.How can I optimize the code
2. Are there rules that I can follow to optimize the code when some other questions occur?

Comment: It might be faster to use `std::thread`s or `pthreads` but in any case you will want to refactor the multithreading to minimize [false sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing), thread sleeping and resuming, thread construction and destruction.

Comment: The code is crazeee - all the work (and there isn't very much of that at all) is either inside an atomic or critical section.  Both `atomic` and `critical` effectively serialise execution; they're meant to be used sparingly inside parallel sections.  And running 128 threads on an 8-core processor is probably not a good idea either.  First make your code parallel then run it on 8 threads and see how you get on.